# how to use pandas to draw many picture

Tags: csv, pandas

there are many lines in the excel，i want to draw a picture for every line, but there are too many lines,if i show them in one picture(using the subplots=True), every one becomes very small(just like the picture in the attachment).
i want to how to draw many picture, not like the subplot.

below are my data in excel

```
    2017/2/13   2017/2/14   2017/2/15   2017/2/16   2017/2/17
sds_24g_4x1g    75  0   0   0   0
hsb_stk()   0   0   0   0   0
nic_rx_cluster  0   0   0   0   0
sds_16g_8x2p5g  80  0   0   0   0
sds_20g_4x2p5g  80  0   0   0   0
sds_8g_12x2p5g  81  0   0   0   0
nic_rx_truncate 0   0   0   0   0
sds_24g_4x10g   82  0   0   0   0
sds_8x10g   83  0   0   0   0
opri_rmk_cpuas  0   0   0   0   0
cfi_rmk_vlan    0   0   0   0   0
ipri_rmk_cpuas  0   0   0   0   0
cfi_rmk_cpuas   0   0   0   0   0
sds_16x2p5g 83  0   0   0   0
dei_rmk_cpuas   100 0   0   0   0
sds_24x2p5g 84  0   0   0   0
opri_rmk_mix    0   0   0   0   0
ipri_rmk_mix    0   0   0   0   0
dei_rmk_table   0   0   0   0   0
cfi_rmk_table   0   0   0   0   0
chip_pll_fcov   0   0   0   0   0
sds_24fe_4x1g   91  0   0   0   0
cov_vlan    0   0   0   0   0
cov_l2  0   0   0   0   0
pwr_saving  0   0   0   0   0
cov_trunk   0   0   0   0   0
dscp_rmk_mix    0   0   0   0   0
cov_qid 0   0   0   0   0
cov_led_scan    93  0   0   0   0
```

[image]

Comment: OK you've stated you have a problem so how do you intend to solve it? You've not shown what the desired result is

Comment: i want to use python to use one excel to generate many separate pictures, suppose the excel has 100 lines, i want to generate 20 pictures(one pictures has 5 subplot).

Comment: i try to separate the data into many csv file, it seems the csv can't deal with many sheets。